# Calculate rowsums of columns based on predefined range

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataset similar to this:

```
  dataset <- structure(
list(
Participant.Id = 1:5,

x1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L),
x2 = c(15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L),
x3 = c(20L, 25L, NA, 45L, NA),
x4 = c(25L, 30L, NA, 50L, NA),
x5 = c(NA, 35L, NA, 55L, NA),
x6 = c(NA, 35L, NA, NA, NA),

y1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L),
y2 = c(15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L),
y3 = c(20L, 25L, NA, 45L, NA),
y4 = c(25L, 30L, NA, 50L, NA),
y5 = c(NA, 35L, NA, 55L, NA),
y6 = c(NA, 35L, NA, NA, NA),

z1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L),
z2 = c(15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L),
z3 = c(20L, 25L, NA, 45L, NA),
z4 = c(25L, 30L, NA, 50L, NA),
z5 = c(NA, 35L, NA, 55L, NA),
z6 = c(NA, 35L, NA, NA, NA),

mt1_oranges_vol = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L),
mt2_oranges_vol = c(110L, 210L, 310L, 410L, 510L),
mt3_oranges_vol = c(120L, 220L, NA, 420L, 520L),
mt4_oranges_vol = c(130L, 230L, NA, 430L, NA),
mt5_oranges_vol = c(NA, 240L, NA, NA, NA),
mt6_oranges_vol = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
 
mt1_pears_vol = c(101L, 201L, 301L, 401L, 501L),
mt2_pears_vol = c(111L, 211L, 311L, 411L, 511L),
mt3_pears_vol = c(121L, 221L, NA, 421L, 521L),
mt4_pears_vol = c(131L, 231L, NA, 431L, NA),
mt5_pears_vol = c(NA, 241L, NA, NA, NA),
mt6_pears_vol = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),

mt1_apples_vol = c(102L, 202L, 302L, 402L, 502L),
mt2_apples_vol = c(112L, 212L, 312L, 412L, 512L),
mt3_apples_vol = c(122L, 222L, NA, 422L, 522L),
mt4_apples_vol = c(132L, 232L, NA, 432L, NA),
mt5_apples_vol = c(NA, 242L, NA, NA, NA),
mt6_apples_vol = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),


class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L)
)
```

I need to make a total column that is the sum of mt1_apples_vol + mt1_pears_vol + mt1_oranges_vol; mt2_apples_vol + mt2_pears_vol + mt2_oranges_vol etc.

Currently, I calculate it as:

```
dataset <- dataset  %>%
mutate(ct1_total_vol = rowSums(select(., starts_with("mt1_")), na.rm = F),
   mt2_total_vol = rowSums(select(., starts_with("mt2_")), na.rm = F),
   mt3_total_vol = rowSums(select(., starts_with("mt3_")), na.rm = F)
   )
```

However, In the future, more measurements might be added. Therefore I would like it to iterate over mt_range:

```
mt_range <- 1:6
```

I have not been able to write the code in such a way that it creates a new column and chooses all variables based on the mt_range

Answer (score 4):

Here's the one-liner with `across`:

```r
dataset |> 
  mutate(across(contains("orange"),
                 \(x) rowSums(pick(starts_with(gsub("_.*", "", cur_column()))), na.rm = F),
                .names = "{gsub('_.*', '', .col)}_total_vol"))
```

---

It can be a bit intimidating at first, so let's break it down:

1. We select one set of columns that share a fruit name (here "orange", but can be others) -- `across(contains("orange"), ...)`
2. For all of those columns, we compute the `rowSums`over all the columns that share the same prefix (`mtX`). To get the column that share the same prefix, we `pick` columns that `starts_with` the same values before the first underscore: `gsub("_.*", "", cur_column()))`
3. We use the `.names` argument to construct the new column names: `"{gsub('_.*', '', .col)}_total_vol"`. The syntax is a bit peculiar because it uses [`glue`](https://glue.tidyverse.org/) syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It worked perfectly and the explanation made it easy to understand why it works.

Answer (score 3):

You'll find this a lot easier if you put the data in long form. We can use the `names_pattern` argument of [`tidyr::pivot_longer()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) to separate the number and word following `"mt_"` from names like `"mt1_apples_vol"` into two columns,`"fruit_num"` and `"fruit"`.

Then it's simply a case of grouping by the fruit number and calculating the sum.

```r
dataset |>
    tidyr::pivot_longer(
        cols = starts_with("mt"),
        names_pattern = "^mt(\\d)_(\\w+)_vol$",
        names_to = c("fruit_num", "fruit")
    ) |>
    summarise(
        total_vol = sum(value, na.rm = FALSE),
        .by = c(Participant.Id, fruit_num)
    )

# # A tibble: 30 × 3
#    Participant.Id fruit_num total_vol
#             <int> <chr>         <int>
#  1              1 1               303
#  2              1 2               333
#  3              1 3               363
#  4              1 4               393
#  5              1 5                NA
#  6              1 6                NA
#  7              2 1               603
#  8              2 2               633
#  9              2 3               663
# 10              2 4               693
# # ℹ 20 more rows
```

If you want it wide form you can pipe the above back into `tidyr::pivot_wider()`.

The data in the exact original format you specify (which I think is unlikely to be the best format) can be obtained by pivoting back into wide form and using `dplyr::inner_join()`

```r
dataset |>
    inner_join(
        dataset |>
            tidyr::pivot_longer(
                cols = starts_with("mt"),
                names_pattern = "^mt(\\d)_(\\w+)_vol$",
                names_to = c("fruit_num", "fruit")
            ) |>
            summarise(
                total_vol = sum(value, na.rm = FALSE),
                .by = c(Participant.Id, fruit_num)
            ) |>
            tidyr::pivot_wider(
                names_from = fruit_num,
                values_from = total_vol,
                names_glue = "mt{.name}_total_vol"
            ),
        by = "Participant.Id"
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response again! For my current code the answer by Mael works nicely. However, since I am swithing between long and wide format quite a bit in my entire code, I will definitvely give this a go at the end when I streamline everything. I had a few courses on R, however, now during my internship I am learning mostly by reading online articles. Is it good practice to switch a lot bewteen long/wide format just to do one mutation at a time, or should I look to bundle multiple actions per pivot? Thnx in advance

Comment: @y.a it depends on what you're doing and the size of your data (i.e. how expensive pivoting is). Generally I would try to have the data in long form as much as possible, only putting it in wide form when it needs to be.

Comment: ah okay! So long is preferred over wide. Right after this section I am doing a left_join for which it was my understanding that it needs to be in wide format

Comment: @y.a a join can be done in long or wide format - you can join on multiple keys (columns). Whether you use long or wide depends to a large extent on the packages that you're using, but as you seem to be using the `tidyverse` you'll find long easier generally (particularly for plotting with `ggplot2`). If you haven't I would read [Tidy Data](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) by Hadley Wickham.

Answer (score 3):

You can try subset the needed columns and then split them into a list by names, and in turn calculate the `rowSums`.

Below is a base R option

```
dfmt <- dataset[startsWith(names(dataset), "mt")]
new_cols <- list2DF(
    lapply(
        split.default(
            dfmt,
            paste0(gsub("_.*", "", names(dfmt)), "_total_vol")
        ),
        rowSums
    )
)
out <- cbind(dataset, new_cols)
```

and you will obtain `out` like below

```
  Participant.Id x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 z6
1              1 10 15 20 25 NA NA 10 15 20 25 NA NA 10 15 20 25 NA NA
2              2 20 25 25 30 35 35 20 25 25 30 35 35 20 25 25 30 35 35
3              3 30 35 NA NA NA NA 30 35 NA NA NA NA 30 35 NA NA NA NA
4              4 40 45 45 50 55 NA 40 45 45 50 55 NA 40 45 45 50 55 NA
5              5 50 55 NA NA NA NA 50 55 NA NA NA NA 50 55 NA NA NA NA
  mt1_oranges_vol mt2_oranges_vol mt3_oranges_vol mt4_oranges_vol
1             100             110             120             130
2             200             210             220             230
3             300             310              NA              NA
4             400             410             420             430
5             500             510             520              NA
  mt5_oranges_vol mt6_oranges_vol mt1_pears_vol mt2_pears_vol mt3_pears_vol
1              NA              NA           101           111           121
2             240              NA           201           211           221
3              NA              NA           301           311            NA
4              NA              NA           401           411           421
5              NA              NA           501           511           521
  mt4_pears_vol mt5_pears_vol mt6_pears_vol mt1_apples_vol mt2_apples_vol
1           131            NA            NA            102            112
2           231           241            NA            202            212
3            NA            NA            NA            302            312
4           431            NA            NA            402            412
5            NA            NA            NA            502            512
  mt3_apples_vol mt4_apples_vol mt5_apples_vol mt6_apples_vol mt1_total_vol
1            122            132             NA             NA           303
2            222            232            242             NA           603
3             NA             NA             NA             NA           903
4            422            432             NA             NA          1203
5            522             NA             NA             NA          1503
  mt2_total_vol mt3_total_vol mt4_total_vol mt5_total_vol mt6_total_vol
1           333           363           393            NA            NA
2           633           663           693           723            NA
3           933            NA            NA            NA            NA
4          1233          1263          1293            NA            NA
5          1533          1563            NA            NA            NA
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response! I tried your method, however, I am running into some issues as for some reason it is deleting the columns that were already present in the dataset such as Participant.Id and the other variables. I think this happens because with this code you specifically subset only these columns? Am I correct in assuming that?

Comment: In the last couple of weeks I have seen `split.default()` a lot. I would like to know when to use it instead of `split()`; couldn't manage to find something useful in the docs. For small vectors, `mean.default()` is (slightly) faster than `mean` as it avoids method dispatch. Is it similar to `mean.default`?

Comment: @Friede `split` is a generic function and applies to dataframe with default, which actually calls `split.data.frame` when the input is a dataframe. When you type `methods(split)`, you will see it has other methods, like `split.Date` and `split.default`. When you type `split.default` in the console, you will see that it takes care of `list` mainly.

Comment: @y.a It shouldn't affect the columns that are already present in the dataset, since all operations work on the `dfmt` to generate new columns. You can see my updated answer and check the `new_cols`.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `dplyr` plus `purrr`:

```
df %>%
 bind_cols(map_dfc(.x = paste0("mt", 1:6),
                   ~ df %>%
                    transmute(!!paste0(.x, "_total_sum") := rowSums(across(starts_with(.x)), na.rm = TRUE))))

  Participant.Id x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 z6 mt1_oranges_vol
1              1 10 15 20 25 NA NA 10 15 20 25 NA NA 10 15 20 25 NA NA             100
2              2 20 25 25 30 35 35 20 25 25 30 35 35 20 25 25 30 35 35             200
3              3 30 35 NA NA NA NA 30 35 NA NA NA NA 30 35 NA NA NA NA             300
4              4 40 45 45 50 55 NA 40 45 45 50 55 NA 40 45 45 50 55 NA             400
5              5 50 55 NA NA NA NA 50 55 NA NA NA NA 50 55 NA NA NA NA             500
  mt2_oranges_vol mt3_oranges_vol mt4_oranges_vol mt5_oranges_vol mt6_oranges_vol
1             110             120             130              NA              NA
2             210             220             230             240              NA
3             310              NA              NA              NA              NA
4             410             420             430              NA              NA
5             510             520              NA              NA              NA
  mt1_pears_vol mt2_pears_vol mt3_pears_vol mt4_pears_vol mt5_pears_vol mt6_pears_vol
1           101           111           121           131            NA            NA
2           201           211           221           231           241            NA
3           301           311            NA            NA            NA            NA
4           401           411           421           431            NA            NA
5           501           511           521            NA            NA            NA
  mt1_apples_vol mt2_apples_vol mt3_apples_vol mt4_apples_vol mt5_apples_vol
1            102            112            122            132             NA
2            202            212            222            232            242
3            302            312             NA             NA             NA
4            402            412            422            432             NA
5            502            512            522             NA             NA
  mt6_apples_vol mt1_total_sum mt2_total_sum mt3_total_sum mt4_total_sum mt5_total_sum
1             NA           303           333           363           393             0
2             NA           603           633           663           693           723
3             NA           903           933             0             0             0
4             NA          1203          1233          1263          1293             0
5             NA          1503          1533          1563             0             0
  mt6_total_sum
1             0
2             0
3             0
4             0
5             0
```

The range is specified in `paste0("mt", 1:6)`, and could be adjusted to any other.

Comment: Hi first of all thank you for your answer! I had tried something similar before, however, my issue is that the range of 1:6 might change after I leave the company. I want to future proof it so that no matter the range, the code will keep working. Therefore, I predefined the range as a variable, however, it did not work for me.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what did not work?

Comment: I think that in the method I used, which was  bind_cols(map_dfc(.x = paste0("mt", ct_range) it copied 1:7 behind it instead of 1, 2, 3, 4 etc

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` in `sapply` to loop over *mt* columns then `cbind` the `rowSums`.

```
> df |> cbind(mt=sapply(1:6, \(i) rowSums(df[grep(sprintf('mt%s', i), names(df))])))
  Participant.Id x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 z6 mt1_oranges_vol
1              1 10 15 20 25 NA NA 10 15 20 25 NA NA 10 15 20 25 NA NA             100
2              2 20 25 25 30 35 35 20 25 25 30 35 35 20 25 25 30 35 35             200
3              3 30 35 NA NA NA NA 30 35 NA NA NA NA 30 35 NA NA NA NA             300
4              4 40 45 45 50 55 NA 40 45 45 50 55 NA 40 45 45 50 55 NA             400
5              5 50 55 NA NA NA NA 50 55 NA NA NA NA 50 55 NA NA NA NA             500
  mt2_oranges_vol mt3_oranges_vol mt4_oranges_vol mt5_oranges_vol mt6_oranges_vol
1             110             120             130              NA              NA
2             210             220             230             240              NA
3             310              NA              NA              NA              NA
4             410             420             430              NA              NA
5             510             520              NA              NA              NA
  mt1_pears_vol mt2_pears_vol mt3_pears_vol mt4_pears_vol mt5_pears_vol mt6_pears_vol
1           101           111           121           131            NA            NA
2           201           211           221           231           241            NA
3           301           311            NA            NA            NA            NA
4           401           411           421           431            NA            NA
5           501           511           521            NA            NA            NA
  mt1_apples_vol mt2_apples_vol mt3_apples_vol mt4_apples_vol mt5_apples_vol
1            102            112            122            132             NA
2            202            212            222            232            242
3            302            312             NA             NA             NA
4            402            412            422            432             NA
5            502            512            522             NA             NA
  mt6_apples_vol mt.1 mt.2 mt.3 mt.4 mt.5 mt.6
1             NA  303  333  363  393   NA   NA
2             NA  603  633  663  693  723   NA
3             NA  903  933   NA   NA   NA   NA
4             NA 1203 1233 1263 1293   NA   NA
5             NA 1503 1533 1563   NA   NA   NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Participant.Id = 1:5, x1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 
50L), x2 = c(15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L), x3 = c(20L, 25L, NA, 45L, 
NA), x4 = c(25L, 30L, NA, 50L, NA), x5 = c(NA, 35L, NA, 55L, 
NA), x6 = c(NA, 35L, NA, NA, NA), y1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 
50L), y2 = c(15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L), y3 = c(20L, 25L, NA, 45L, 
NA), y4 = c(25L, 30L, NA, 50L, NA), y5 = c(NA, 35L, NA, 55L, 
NA), y6 = c(NA, 35L, NA, NA, NA), z1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 
50L), z2 = c(15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L), z3 = c(20L, 25L, NA, 45L, 
NA), z4 = c(25L, 30L, NA, 50L, NA), z5 = c(NA, 35L, NA, 55L, 
NA), z6 = c(NA, 35L, NA, NA, NA), mt1_oranges_vol = c(100L, 200L, 
300L, 400L, 500L), mt2_oranges_vol = c(110L, 210L, 310L, 410L, 
510L), mt3_oranges_vol = c(120L, 220L, NA, 420L, 520L), mt4_oranges_vol = c(130L, 
230L, NA, 430L, NA), mt5_oranges_vol = c(NA, 240L, NA, NA, NA
), mt6_oranges_vol = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mt1_pears_vol = c(101L, 
201L, 301L, 401L, 501L), mt2_pears_vol = c(111L, 211L, 311L, 
411L, 511L), mt3_pears_vol = c(121L, 221L, NA, 421L, 521L), mt4_pears_vol = c(131L, 
231L, NA, 431L, NA), mt5_pears_vol = c(NA, 241L, NA, NA, NA), 
    mt6_pears_vol = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mt1_apples_vol = c(102L, 
    202L, 302L, 402L, 502L), mt2_apples_vol = c(112L, 212L, 312L, 
    412L, 512L), mt3_apples_vol = c(122L, 222L, NA, 422L, 522L
    ), mt4_apples_vol = c(132L, 232L, NA, 432L, NA), mt5_apples_vol = c(NA, 
    242L, NA, NA, NA), mt6_apples_vol = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```